# python, GPA calculator, about working code

Tags: python

this is a GPA calculator code in my textbook. I'd like to ask about a few this I don't understand here.

```
# Semester GPA Calculation

def convertGrade(grade):
    if grade == 'A+':
        return 4
    if grade == 'A':
        return 3.7
    if grade == 'A-':
        return 3.3
    if grade == 'B+':
        return 3.0
    if grade == 'B':
        return 2.7
    if grade == 'B-':
        return 2.3
    if grade == 'C+':
        return 2.0
    if grade == 'C':
        return 1.7
    if grade == 'C-':
        return 1.3
    if grade == 'D+':
        return 1.0
    if grade == 'D':
        return 0.7
    if grade == 'D-':
        return 0.3
    else:
        return 0


def getGrades():
semester_info = []
more_grades = True
empty_str = ''

    while more_grades:
        course_grade = input('Enter grade (hit Enter if done): ')
        while course_grade not in ['A+', 'A', 'A-', 'B+', 'B', 'B-', 'C+', 'C', 'C-', 'D+', 'D', 'D-', 'E+', 'E', 'E-', 'F', empty_str]:
        course_grade = input('Enter letter grade you received: ')
     if course_grade == empty_str:
            more_grades = False
     else:
         num_credits = int(input('Enter number of credits: '))
         semester_info.append([num_credits, course_grade])

 return semester_info

def calculateGPA(sem_grades_info, cumm_gpa_info):
    sem_quality_pts = 0
    sem_credits = 0
    current_cumm_gpa, total_credits = cumm_gpa_info

    for k in range(len(sem_grades_info)):
        num_credits, letter_grade = sem_grades_info[k]

        sem_quality_pts = sem_quality_pts + \
                      num_credits * convertGrade(letter_grade)

        sem_credits = sem_credits + num_credits


    sem_gpa = sem_quality_pts / sem_credits
    new_cumm_gpa = (current_cumm_gpa * total_credits + sem_gpa * \
                sem_credits) / (total_credits + sem_credits)

    return (sem_gpa, new_cumm_gpa)

# ---- main

# program greeting
print('This program calculates new semester and cumulative GPAs\n')

# get current GPA info
total_credits = int(input('Enter total number of earned credits: '))
cumm_gpa = float(input('Enter your current cummulative GPA: '))
cumm_gpa_info = (cumm_gpa, total_credits)

# get current semester grade info
print()
semester_grades = getGrades()

# calculate semester gpa and new cumulative gpa
semester_gpa, cumm_gpa = calculateGPA(semester_grades, cumm_gpa_info)

#display semester gpa and new cummulative gpa
print('\nYour semester GPA is', format(semester_gpa, '.2f'))
print('Your new cummulative GPA is', format(cumm_gpa, '.2f'))
```

What does `current_cumm_gpa, total_credits = cumm_gpa_info` mean below? Does it create a new array? I tried simpler but it doesn't work.

```
  def calculateGPA(sem_grades_info, cumm_gpa_info):
      sem_quality_pts = 0
      sem_credits = 0
      current_cumm_gpa, total_credits = cumm_gpa_info
```

Comment: `a, b = c` means that elements of iterable type object `c` is assigned to `a` and `b` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

From  this line:

```
cumm_gpa_info = (cumm_gpa, total_credits)
```

We can see that `cumm_gpa_info` is [a tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) of two values. Then `current_cumm_gpa, total_credits = cumm_gpa_info` *unpacks* the values in the tuple to two variables, the first to `current_cumm_gpa` and the second to `total_credits`. It's a simpler way of doing:

```
current_cumm_gpa = cumm_gpa_info[0]
total_credits = cumm_gpa_info[1]
```

From the docs:

> This is called, appropriately enough, *sequence unpacking* and works for
>   any sequence on the right-hand side. Sequence unpacking requires that
>   there are as many variables on the left side of the equals sign as
>   there are elements in the sequence. Note that multiple assignment is
>   really just a combination of tuple packing and sequence unpacking.

Answer (score 0):

Tracing your program we see the following :

```
>>> total_credits = int(input('Enter total number of earned credits: '))
    #3.2
>>> cumm_gpa = float(input('Enter your current cummulative GPA: '))
    #4.6
>>> cumm_gpa_info = (cumm_gpa, total_credits)

>>> cumm_gpa_info
    (3.2 , 4.6)

>>> type(cumm_gpa_info)
    Tuple
```

So we see that `cumm_gpa_info` is a `Tuple`. Now this is passed to the function.

```
>>> ... = calculateGPA(semester_grades, cumm_gpa_info)

#inside function
>>> current_cumm_gpa, total_credits = cumm_gpa_info
#current_cumm_gpa, total_credits = (3.2 , 4.6)

>>> current_cumm_gpa
    3.2
>>> total_credits
    4.6
```

So as we can see, the values were `unpacked` from the `tuple` and assigned to `current_cumm_gpa` & `total_credits` respectively.

It is similar to doing :

```
>>> current_cumm_gpa = cumm_gpa_info[0]
>>> total_credits = cumm_gpa_info[1]
```

*Note : sorry if its not exactly how it would look on a console. Can't get to my PC, writing it out on my mobile right now. So have put it approximately how it would look.*